# Solr more like this don't return score while specify `mlt.count`

Tags: solr, morelikethis

I'm using solr's more like this to analyze the most similar documents. But while I specify `mlt.count` argument and if it is not 15, the score don't show. The more like this arguments is `mlt=true&mlt.fl=text&mlt.count=12`, while `text` is the filed that has term vector. And the `fl` argument is `*,score`. I queried this url:

`http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=id%3A1967956383&wt=json&indent=true&mlt=true&mlt.fl=text&mlt.count=12`.

When I specify `mlt.count=15`, the score shows up. And after that, I query `mlt.count=12` again, it shows up, too.

My solr version is 4.0.

Does anybody have any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been documented as a SOLR bug [SOLR-5042](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-5042), and a patch posted against solr version 4.3.  I've relocated that patch back to 4.2.1 and seen that it fixes this behavior there.

If you query the /mlt handler directly, instead of using the mlt component under the /select handler, you can work around this issue, as the handler accepts its count as rows=12 instead of mlt.count=12.

Comment: what you suggest works well to get the score but it introduces a new problem. Lets take an example: when I perform my query with select?qt=mlt... I obtain 33 docs in 'response' and then a list of 5 moreLikeThis for each doc (with no score). When I change for mlt?...its says I have 33 NumFound in 'match' but only one of them is returned and it is performing the moreLikeThis on the only document returned. Do you have a suggestion to solve this? Thank you

Comment: My response was to the specific question above, how to fix the scores not showing up when the count was 15, and the patch to SOLR-5042 fixes that, as does upgrading to 4.6 where the problem was fixed. (When I wrote my response above, 4.6 had not yet been released.)

Comment: The first behavior you describe, using the Select handler, with version 4.6 or after patching SOLR-5042, you should see the score 
along with the documents in the MLT response, provided you include mlt.fl=score,* in the input parameters.

Comment: If you invoke the MoreLikeThis handler directly, typically one specifies in the query the id of the document, so it will match on one, and the MLT list returns documents similar to that one, up to the specified count. This is illustrated in the select query string above, .../select?q=id&3A1967956383... I'm not sure one should call this "a new problem", as the name of the handler is MoreLikeThis, 
not MoreLikeThese. The wiki docs call attention to the "MoreLikeThese" facility of the MLT component,
not the MLT handler. <http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis>

Comment: In my case, I wanted to do the same thing, query on a specific document, but using the /select handler, as it supports queries against multiple shards.  That required fixing two more issues, SOLR-1085 and SOLR-5521, so that I could retrieve the MLT response documents through the Java client, and so that the MLT search of 
each shard for matching documents would not blow up on a document id beginning with a leading minus.

Comment: In my comment above about the Select handler, to cause the score to be returned along with the matching documents, the parameter should be fl=score,* not mlt.fl=score,*